# Push a non-existing boolean value to state and share across components

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to make it so a user can click on a `ArtImage` which renders a div - once it does this it should add the value of `selected` to the selected `images` state and display the total number of selected `images`, while also using `input type="radio"` to trigger the clicking of the image. Is there a way to share this state across the components while also updating these values?

Data

```
const images = [
    {
        imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/id/1003/300/300"
    },
    {
        imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/id/1005/300/300"
    },
    {
        imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/id/1009/300/300"
    },
    {
        imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/id/1010/300/300"
    },
    {
        imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300"
    },
    {
        imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/id/1025/300/300"
    },
    {
        imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/id/1027/300/300"
    },
    ...
];
```

```
const ArtImage = ({ image, currentImage }) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false);

    const handleSelect = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
    };

    return (
        <div
            onClick={handleSelect}
            style={{
                display: "inline-block",
                position: "relative",
                cursor: "pointer"
            }}
        >
            <input type="radio" checked={selected} />
            <img src={image.imageUrl} />
        </div>
    );
};

const ArtSelection = ({ art }) => {
    const [images, setImages] = React.useState(art);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{images.selected}/12 posts selected</p>
            {images.map((e, i) => {
                return <ArtImage image={e} />;
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/adam-ginther/pen/PopwNag?editors=0110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a image count state and pass it to the child component.

```
 const ArtSelection = ({ art = [] }) => { //default the art props to an array to prevent error while rendering
        const [images, setImages] = React.useState(art);
        const [ imageCount, setImageCount ] = React.useState(0);
    
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{imageCount}/ {images.length} posts selected</p>
                {images.map((e, i) => {
                    return <ArtImage image={e} updateImageCount={setImageCount} />;
                })}
                <p>Total Selected: {imageCount} </p>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Then in the child component, use useEffect to update the counter.

```
const ArtImage = ({ image, currentImage, updateImageCount }) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (selected) {
         updateImageCount(prev => prev+1)
      } else {
         updateImageCount(prev => prev-1) 
      }

    },[selected])
    const handleSelect = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
       
    
    };

    return (
        <div
            onClick={handleSelect}
            style={{
                display: "inline-block",
                position: "relative",
                cursor: "pointer"
            }}
        >
            <input type="radio" checked={selected} />
            <img src={image.imageUrl} />
        </div>
    );
};
```